# Three Layer architecture using ADO.NET Entity Framework & Simple ADO.NET Classes

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I want a demo who teaches me Three Layer architecture nicely

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700340.aspx